# Print only the contents of modal in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, modal-dialog, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to print the modal contents of ng-bootstrap modal in Angular. The modal contains a table and so I want the doc to be printed in same format. I want the same functionality given [here](https://codepen.io/clagosv/pen/YjQdao) but unable to implement it.

According to this link, it sets the visibility of `body` to `hidden` during print and shows only modal content. But in Angular, we use components and so setting `body: hidden` doesn't work. It prints out the whole document (modal along with background component, header and footer which I don't want).

I've followed alot of solutions but unable to do so.

I've also tried appending the printable modal content to new window but writing to new window requires only strings. I'm using table in modal so I want the same style of table to get print.

How can I achieve this?

Edit 1 : This is the modal content I want to print:

```
<div id="printable">
    <div class="row shipping">
      <div class="col-4">
        <h6>SHIPPING ADDRESS</h6>
        <p>
          {{ this.order.shipName }} : {{ this.order.addrLine1 }},
          {{ this.order.area1 }}, {{ this.order.area2 }},
          {{ this.order.countryCode }} - {{ this.order.pin }}
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <h6>SHIPPING METHOD</h6>
        <p>Standard</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <h6>ACCOUNT PAID</h6>
        <p>Paypal Account: {{ this.order.order.payerEmail }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br /><br />
    <div class="card">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>ITEM</th>
          <th>DETAILS</th>
          <th>QTY</th>
          <th>TOTAL</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <img
              [src]="this.order.order.image"
              style="height: 70px; width: 70px"
            />
          </td>
          <td>
            {{ this.order.order.category }}
          </td>
          <td>{{ this.order.order.quantity }}</td>
          <td>${{ this.order.order.amtPaid }}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 20px">
      <div class="col-8"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h5>
          <b>ORDER TOTAL</b> : <span>${{ this.order.order.amtPaid }}</span>
        </h5>
        <br />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

On button click, I want to print this div content as it is

```
<div class="modal-footer" id="non-printable">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onPrint()">
      Print Receipt
    </button>
    <button
      type="button"
      class="btn btn-secondary"
      (click)="modal.dismiss('cancel click')"
    >
      Cancel
    </button>
  </div>
```

Method to print the modal content:

```
onPrint() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("printable");
    var domClone = elem.cloneNode(true)
    var $printSection = document.getElementById("printSection");

    if (!$printSection) {
      let $printSection = document.createElement("div");
      $printSection.id = "printSection";
      document.body.appendChild($printSection);
      $printSection.innerHTML = "";
      $printSection.appendChild(domClone);
      window.print();    // only modal content should get print
    }
  }
```

In css:

```
@media screen {
  #printSection {
      display: none;
  }
}

@media print {
  body * {
    visibility:hidden;
  }
  #printSection, #printSection * {
    visibility:visible;
  }
  #printSection {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Put your code here so that we can provide work around. Unless you do so we can't suggest any code changes or fixes

Comment: @HitechHitesh I've added the code. Please review now

Comment: Answer from Hitech Hitesh, would solve the print option for modal dialog, but will completely hide the body tag. So applying this CSS can be risky if you also have print functionality on other screens which are not modal dialogs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need the js code to clone and all its just a css change in the code

```
onPrint() {
      window.print();    
    }
```

**For hiding the header, footer and other stuff that are beyond the scope of the component has to written in global css file i.e. in `style.css`**

```css
/*  
move from component level css to style.css
Here hiding is not required as the same is been displayed on screen

@media screen {
  #printable {
      display: none;
  }
} */

@media print {
  body * {
    visibility:hidden;
  }
  #printable, #printable * {
    visibility:visible;
  }
  #printable {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
  }
}
```

Comment: It works like a charm! Thank you so much. I should have set css in global file.